# Trying to insert data into custom table with php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a simple custom form on localhost. When I click the submit button I get an error Page not found . Nothing is inserted into the table.

I have a php file called insert.php placed in the local xampp/htdocs folder.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "parivaar");

// Check connection
if ($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['first_name']);
$last_name  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['last_name']);
$email      = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES 
('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";
if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Not able to execute the file. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: This was just a trial script. I will be using prepared statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue. My php file was placed in the wrong folder. The php file should be in the htdocs/yourtheme folder.